# Setting relations in QGIS not working in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, relation

I have a set two relation in my QGIS project. One relation called 'Photos' and the other called 'Attitude'. Though in QGIS desktop it seems to work fine but when I transfer it in Qfield it doesn't seem to work. The plus sign in QField attribute form doesn't work. I can make data entry in those child layers individually but not through parent layer.

Below are the settings of one of my relation setup called 'Attitide'.

Fields of my parent layer named 'Stations'

[image]

relation settings

[image]

Settings of the child field

[image]

Here is the attribute form from Qfield where the '+' sign does not seems to work

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to do. Presumably for photos you are seeking to add child photos. If so, see here: https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/pictures/ .

Attitude should be similar, but perhaps no attachment widget.

I can see you have configured

Comment: This feature definitely works in QField (but not polymorphic relations, although there is a workaround).

In order to assist further you need to show details of primary and foreign keys - are they the same data type? Is the primary key (uuid) populated?

Comment: @Oisin thank you. You were right my data types were not same. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'll post my comments as a reply. I'd be grateful if you coudl mark as solution. Thanks O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More details are required to assess fully.

But is you are seeking to add 1:n photos see here: docs.qfield.org/how-to/pictures.

The relation 'Attitude' should be similar, but perhaps no attachment widget. This feature definitely works in QField (but not polymorphic relations, although there is a workaround).

In the meantime, common issues to check are:

- are primary and foreign keys the same data type?
- Is the primary key (uuid) populated?